# Color change of Material UI chip component on click not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have some chips that work like tabs on my page. They are mutually exclusive and change color when selected. How do I achieve this.
I think it has got something to do with variant = "outlined". I do want the initial chip to have 'outlined' and onClick, it needs to have a background

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
      overrides: {
        MuiChip: {
          clickableColorSecondary: {
            '&:hover, &:focus': {
              backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
            '&:active': {
              backgroundColor: 'green',
            },
          },
        }
      }
    });
```

Chips

```
<Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary" classes={{ badge: classes.badge }} >
      <Chip
        label="Label 1"
        clickable
        className={classes.chip}
        color="secondary"
        variant="outlined"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </Badge>

<Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary" classes={{ badge: classes.badge }} >
      <Chip
        label="Label 2"
        clickable
        className={classes.chip}
        color="secondary"
        variant="outlined"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </Badge>

<Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary" classes={{ badge: classes.badge }} >
      <Chip
        label="Label 3"
        clickable
        className={classes.chip}
        color="secondary"
        variant="outlined"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </Badge>
```

This does not override the selected chip style as I expected

I also tried wrapping it in another theme

```
const chipsTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiChip: {
        clickableColorPrimary: {
          '&:hover, &:focus': {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
          '&:active': {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          },
        },
        clickableColorSecondary: {
          '&:hover, &:focus': {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
          '&:active': {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          },
        }
      }
    }
  });

<MuiThemeProvider theme={chipsTheme}>
        <Chip
            label="INVENTORY"
            clickable
            className={classes.chip}
            color="secondary"
            variant="outlined"
            onClick={handleClick}
        />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
```

But it does not change its style at all. How Can I make its change color on click and also clear other colors when another chip is clicked?

Comment: This seems to work here: https://codesandbox.io/s/94451ppw5y. It turns green when "active" (i.e. as it is being clicked -- while the mouse button is down). Are you trying to have one remain looking "selected" after you finish clicking on it? If so, how are you tracking which one is "selected"?

Comment: I guess I can just do a local State change and do something on the lines of handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ color: 'primary', variant: 'default' });
  };